# Is it possible to have the line chart data points in highcharts to be represented as a rectangle instead of a circle?

Tags: highcharts, shapes, linechart

I have two series in my highchart. One bar and one line chart. I want the datapoints of the line chart be represented at rectangle or straight lines instead of dots. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for "square"? Explained [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.marker.symbol).